# Scheduled refresh with Azure SQL only data grayed out

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database

### Setup

I have around 7GB of data in an Azure SQL DB which will continue to grow. PBIX report at just under 1GB. Currently I'm using the import method to work with the data and then publishing the report. Data loaded to PBI Desktop and then published to a workspace. All the data comes from the same Azure DB and I've already checked the Firewall option about internal Azure connections.

### Problem

I am unable to set a scheduled refresh because I haven't filled out a data source credential, but that option is grayed out so I can't fill it in. All the data comes from the same Azure DB (some used to be CSV files, but I just created tables in the DB instead and replaced the data), which is online, so I should not need a gateway.

### Thoughts

Maybe the capacity of the Office tenant (not sure if it's A1-3 or larger, not sure how to check) is full, as the report is just shy of 1 GB and the error shown is just badly handled?

Maybe because I had some of the data as files first, it's not recognizing that it's all now under the same DB connection? (I deleted the report with the dataset and re-uploaded)

Maybe I should change it to "Direct Query" (which I think makes me loose some of the things I've done in the report) and pay for more DB use instead, if this is something that's not possible, although this seems like the best way since it's MS and MS.

Maybe PBI just hates me.

### Error message:

Last refresh failed: Tue Apr 06 2021 22:39:08 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) Scheduled refresh has been disabled. Data source error: Scheduled refresh is disabled because at least one data source is missing credentials. To start the refresh again, go to this dataset's settings page and enter credentials for all data sources. Then reactivate scheduled refresh.

Comment: You can copy and paste visuals between two different Power BI Desktop files (.pbix) now so one suggestion on troubleshooting is to create a completely blank file, copy over your database queries and visuals and then see if that can be scheduled.  It's unlikely Power BI hates you : )

Comment: It could also be permissions.  You have a Power BI Pro license and you publish to a a shared (not your own) workspace?  See if someone with more permissions than you (eg workspace admin) can change the settings.

Comment: Ended up removing columns that were not needed. It looks like the report actually updates daily... but I'm not quite sure how as I have not specified any schedule or anything like that.